# Contact Picker in PreferenceFragment (failure delivering result error)

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm using PreferenceFragment for my settings page where I have one preference that onclick will open up contact to choose and return the result. However, it has a failure delivering result error.

This is my preferencefragment class

```
public class SettingsXML extends PreferenceFragment {

private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
final static int PICK_CONTACT = 99;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // set background to Drawable
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

    // Get Custom contact Pref
    Preference customContact = (Preference)findPreference("prefPick");
    customContact.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, PICK_CONTACT);
            return true;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_CONTACT:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        Uri contactData = data.getData();
                        // contactData returns some value
                        Log.i(TAG, "" + contactData);
                        String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER};
                        // Something wrong at cursor?
                        Cursor cursor = ctx.getContentResolver()
                                .query(contactData, projection, null, null, null);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();

                        // Retrieve the phone number from the NUMBER column
                        int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
                        String number = cursor.getString(column);

                        Log.i(TAG, "" + number);
                    }
                } else {
                       //
                }
                return;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

And my logcat.

```
05-02 17:36:27.496: W/dalvikvm(6142): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4e3b908)
05-02 17:36:27.906: D/dalvikvm(6142): GC_CONCURRENT freed 356K, 10% free 4398K/4864K, paused 12ms+64ms, total 146ms
05-02 17:36:30.607: E/AndroidRuntime(6142): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 17:36:30.607: E/AndroidRuntime(6142): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:0, request=99, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/1906i7ef0c7d80ffe6bca/2 flg=0x1 }} to activity {SettingsFragment}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 17:36:30.607: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3319)
05-02 17:36:30.607: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3362)
05-02 17:36:30.607: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-02 17:36:30.607: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
05-02 17:36:30.607: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-02 17:36:30.607: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-02 17:36:30.607: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
05-02 17:36:30.607: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 17:36:30.607: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-02 17:36:30.607: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-02 17:36:30.607: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-02 17:36:30.607: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 17:36:30.607: E/AndroidRuntime(6142): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 17:36:30.607: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at SettingsXML.onActivityResult(SettingsXML.java:80)
05-02 17:36:30.607: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5297)
05-02 17:36:30.607: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3315)
05-02 17:36:30.607: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     ... 11 more
```

I do have the permission set at manifest.

Comment: +1. I am having a similar problem. I am not using fragments though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577515/intent-action-pick-only-works-for-some-contacts. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: What on line 80: SettingsXML.onActivityResult(SettingsXML.java:80), it's not a permission issue but a null pointer.